# Convert array to an object (or ignore array definition and go directly to objects inside it) on decoding JSON in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have a somewhat badly designed JSON, which I receive from the server. Here's a similar simple one that demonstrates the problem:

```
let example1 = """
{
    "id":123,
    "name":"John Doe",
    "otherInfo": [
        {
            "address": "789 This st., Sydney"
        },
        {
            "allKnownAddresses": [
                "123 A Street, NY",
                "Paradise Hotel, Bahamas"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

As you see the `otherInfo` is returned as an array of objects. But really it's an object with a bunch of fields (of various types - `String`, `[String]` and even some other structures), which *never repeat*, and (based on context and use), I would much rather store `otherInfo` as a struct, than array:

```
struct OtherInfo: Codable {

    var address: String?
    var allKnownAddresses: [String]?
}
```

It means that my parent structure would look like this:

```
struct Person: Codable {

    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var otherInfo: OtherInfo? // not [OtherInfo]?, but a single object
}
```

Of course automatic decoding is not happy about this. So I wonder **is there a way to skip the array(?) to decode its members, as if they are fields of an object; or decode an array as an object?**

The "normal" decoding would look like this:

```
extension OtherInfo {

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        for key in container.allKeys {
            switch key {
            case .address:
                address = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
            case .allKnownAddresses:
                allKnownAddresses = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .allKnownAddresses)
            }
        }
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case address
        case allKnownAddresses
    }
}
```

But it seems I cannot find the way to link that to parent:

```
extension Person {

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        otherInfo = try container.decode(OtherInfo.self, forKey: .otherInfo) // <-- Problem!
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case otherInfo
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead." and it's very understandable, I know that line is wrong, but how do I get to array's contents which contain `otherInfo`, without treating it as array?

Note:

- this is a simplified example for this question, in reality, it's about 30 fields on top (`Person`) level. So if there's a way to not do manual decoding of the top structure, it's even better. But it's not as important as getting the JSON array "transformed" into JSON object.
- I did see [Decode json array as an object in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66831189/decode-json-array-as-an-object-in-swift) question, but it's different, since in my case there are objects of various types in an array, not just a string dictionary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something simple like this (works for me):

```
extension Person {

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let tempInfo = try container.decode([OtherInfo].self, forKey: .otherInfo) // <-- here
        otherInfo = tempInfo.first // <-- here
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case otherInfo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom decoder for `OtherInfo` that decodes it as an unkeyed container with nested keyed containers, and then iterate through those:

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let otherInfo: OtherInfo?
}

struct OtherInfo: Codable {
    var address: String?
    var allKnownAddresses: [String]?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let subcontainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
            for key in subcontainer.allKeys {
                switch key {
                case .address:
                    address = try subcontainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
                case .allKnownAddresses:
                    allKnownAddresses = try subcontainer.decode([String].self, forKey: .allKnownAddresses)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```swift
let example1 = """
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "otherInfo": [
        {
            "address": "789 This st., Sydney"
        },
        {
            "allKnownAddresses": [
                "123 A Street, NY",
                "Paradise Hotel, Bahamas"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: example1)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Will yield:

> Person(id: 123, name: "John Doe", otherInfo: Optional(xxx.OtherInfo(address: Optional("789 This st., Sydney"), allKnownAddresses: Optional(["123 A Street, NY", "Paradise Hotel, Bahamas"]))))

No manual decoding of the top structure is required.

---

You can obviously customize this as you see fit.

For example, you might add special handling if a particular key is encountered more than once.

Or if you want to make `OtherInfo` properties immutable, you just need to have local vars for all the properties and update them at the end, e.g.:

```swift
struct OtherInfo: Codable {
    let address: String?
    let allKnownAddresses: [String]?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var address: String?
        var allKnownAddresses: [String]?
        
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let subcontainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
            for key in subcontainer.allKeys {
                switch key {
                case .address:
                    address = try subcontainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
                case .allKnownAddresses:
                    allKnownAddresses = try subcontainer.decode([String].self, forKey: .allKnownAddresses)
                }
            }
        }
        
        self.address = address
        self.allKnownAddresses = allKnownAddresses
    }
}
```

But hopefully the above outlines the basic idea.